# Purge command for a Discord bot in C#

Tags: c#, discord

I'm not much of a coder or anything I'm just doing this for fun!
A server I am in with some friends needed a bot, there's of course a ton of bots available but I thought I'd go ahead and try my luck at making my own. I know some basic code and I've written a simple bot in C#, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make a purge command.
What I currently have created is this:

```
RegisterPurgeCommand();
private void RegisterPurgeCommand()
{
   commands.CreateCommand("purge")
   .Parameter("PurgeAmount")
   .Do(async (e) =>
   {
      var messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(convert.ToInt32(e.GetArg("purgeAmount")));
      await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
      await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.GetArg("purgeAmount") + "Messages Deleted.");
   });
}
```

**You can view the code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9D6o.png) in screenshot format if you prefer**

What I initially had was a purge command that deleted messages by x amount in the code, not by the amount I want. For example, what my goal is that in Discord I will do something along the lines of !purge 10 and the last 10 messages are deleted. What I previously had was a !purge command that deleted the previous 10 messages, but if I wanted to do 7 for example, it would still do 10.

The code for that, is:

```
RegisterPurgeCommand();
private void RegisterPurgeCommand()
{
   commands.CreateCommand("purge")
      .Do(async (e) =>
{
   Message[] messagesToDelete;
   messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(100);
   await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
});
}
```

**you can view the code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NOwa.png) in screenshot format if you prefer**

this worked fine, but as I said wasn't really efficient.

Now, I'll be completely honest and say that the the method I'm using now (the one that isn't working) is off of an explanation on Gist.

So what it currently does is... Absolutely nothing.. What it used to do is delete x amount of messages that I told it to delete *in the code* so for example if I wanted to remove 7 messages in the server it would delete 10.

What I want it do is that I can tell the bot to remove x amount of messages in the server regardless by its amount, not that if I want to remove 7 that it removes 10.

Maybe I'm missing something very easily? Maybe I'm just overlooking something stupid? I am legit lost. It is also 6 in the morning as I'm writing this, so it may be that aswell.

Comment: Consider clarifying the text

Comment: Have you tried capital P in e.GetArg("PurgeAmount")?

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing a Parameter PurgeAmount but not actually using it for anything.

```
 messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(100);
```

On this line instead of using 100, use your purge amount parameter

EDIT with my version:

So this is how I did it, ignore the console stuff thats just debugging.

```
                    Console.WriteLine(_channel.Users);
                var userPermissions = _user.GetPermissions(_channel).ManageMessages;
                Console.WriteLine("Admin" + userPermissions);
                int number = int.Parse(_parameter);
                Message[] message = new Message[number];
                message = _channel.DownloadMessages(number).Result;
                if (userPermissions == true)
                {
                    _channel.DeleteMessages(message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Channel Admin: " + _user + " deleted messages from the channel: " + _channel);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User: " + _user + " tried to delete messages from: #" + _channel + " when they aren't an admin there.");
                }
```

Comment: That would be fairly in-efficient as for example I give the purge amount paramater something like 20 but I want 5 messages removed, it would still  remove 20, right?

Comment: but the purgeAmount parameter should be the number of messages you want purging, so why would you give it 20 if you want 5 removed? also if you want I have the code for a delete message command. Want me to post it?

Comment: That would be nice if you could

Comment: Editted it for you